# Creating "team" sub-collections for users

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Let's say there's a user collection.
The relevant information for this question from that collection is:

- username: string,
- teamid: Number,
- totalscore: Number

Now for the final output it should list the teams, list the users under their teams using the teamid, and adding up the totalscore of each user to calculate the teamscore.

However, I can't come up with any way to do that.
I was looking into aggregation for this but eh, it's a bit too far above my hat.

The output for this api is rendered in json using express and mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following aggregation query.
Use a [`group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage with [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) to get the player's name and [`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to get the sum of `totalscore` for a team.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {'$group': {
        '_id': '$teamid',
        'totalscore': {'$sum': '$totalscore'},
        'listofplayers': {'$push':'$username'}
    }
}])
```